# Getting repeated rows for where with or condition

Tags: sql

I am trying find employees that worked during a specific time period and the hours they worked during that time period. My query has to join the employee table that has employee id as pk and uses effective_date and expiration_date as time measures for the employee's position to the timekeeping table that has a pay period id number as pk and also uses effective and expiration dates.

The problem with the expiration date in the employee table is that if the employee is currently employed then the date is '12/31/9999'. I am looking for employees that worked in a certain year and current employees as well as the hours they worked separated by pay periods.

When I take this condition in account in the where with an OR statement, I get duplicates that is employees that have worked the time period I am looking for and beyond as well as duplicate records for the '12/31/9999' and the valid employee in that time period.

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT
            J.EMPL_ID
            ,J.DEPT
            ,J.UNIT
            ,J.LAST_NM
            ,J.FIRST_NM
            ,J.TITLE 
            ,J.EFF_DT
            ,J.EXP_DT
            ,TM1.PPRD_ID
            ,TM1.EMPL_ID
            ,TM1.EXP_DT
            ,TM1.EFF_DT

            --PULLING IN THE DAILY HRS WORKED
             ,(SELECT NVL(SUM(((to_number(SUBSTR(TI.DAY_1, 1
                            ,INSTR(TI.DAY_1, ':', 1, 1)-1),99))*60)+
                (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TI.DAY_1
                            ,INSTR(TI.DAY_1,':', -1, 1)+1),99))),0)
              FROM PPRD_LINE TI
              WHERE
              TI.PPRD_ID=TM1.PPRD_ID
              ) "DAY1"
             ---AND THE REST OF THE DAYS FOR THE WORK PERIOD
    FROM    PPRD_LINE TM1
    JOIN    EMPL J ON TM1.EMPL_ID=J.EMPL_ID

 WHERE
    J.EMPL_ID='some id number' --for test purposes, will need to break down to depts-
    AND
    J.EFF_DT >=TO_DATE('1/1/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')
    AND
    (
    J.EXP_DT<=TO_DATE('12/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')
    OR
    J.EXP_DT=TO_DATE('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY') --I think the problem might be here???
    )

GROUP BY

    J.EMPL_ID
    ,J.DEPT
    ,J.UNIT
    ,J.LAST_NM
    ,J.FIRST_NM
    ,J.TITLE 
    ,J.EFF_DT
    ,J.EXP_DT
    ,TM1.PPRD_ID
    ,TM1.EMPL_ID
    ,TM1.DOC_ID
    ,TM1.EXP_DT
    ,TM1.EFF_DT

ORDER BY
    J.EFF_DT
    ,TM1.EFF_DT
    ,TM1.EXP_DT
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple but at this point I can't see the forest for the trees. Can anyone out there point me in the right direction?

an example of the duplicate records:

for employee 1 for the year of 2012:

```
Empl_ID Dept Unit   Last     First   Title   Eff Date Exp Date   PPRD ID Empl_ID
00001   04   012    Babbage  Charles Somejob 4/1/2012 10/15/2012 0407123 00001 

Exp Date_1 Eff Date_1
4/15/2012  4/1/2012
```

this record repeats 3 times and goes past the pay periods in 2012 to the current pay period in 2013

the subquery I use to convert time to be able to add hrs and mins together to compare down the line.

Comment: Why are you doing the crazy sub-query, that should be a join -- otherwise your performance will be horrible.  This is O(x^2) and could be O(2x)

Comment: The records repeat from the start of the year to the end of the year about three times. The employee has 3 records in the employee table for that time period. 2 that expire in 2012 and one that has a current expiration date of '12/31/999'. Maybe the OR condition in my where is causing the duplicates???

Comment: @Hogan, you cannot make any statement about complexity.  It is a function of the implementation, and the OP did not specify one.

Comment: @Pdizzle, the question is hard to understand without a clear schema description.  Fundamentally you should be able to select pay-period records based on time criteria, and join that result back to the employees.  Use of a subquery in the SELECT clause is nonstandard and will be a source of confusion.  If you think instead about joining sets, you're more likely to get where you want to go.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden - Re: complexity - That is why I made a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Pdizzle - Please show the repeated records if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess and see if this is what you want, remember I could not test so there may be typos.

If this is and especially if it is not, you should read in the FAQ about how to ask good questions.  If this is what you were trying to understand your question should have been answered within about 10 mins.  Because it was not clear what you were asking no one could answer your question.

You should include inputs and outputs and EXPECTED output in your question.  The data you gave was not the output of the select statement (it did not have the DAY1 column).

```
SELECT
   J.EMPL_ID
   ,J.DEPT
   ,J.UNIT
   ,J.LAST_NM
   ,J.FIRST_NM
   ,J.TITLE 
   ,J.EFF_DT
   ,J.EXP_DT
   ,TM1.PPRD_ID
   ,TM1.EMPL_ID
--  ,TM1.EXP_DT  Can't have these if you are summing accross multiple records.
--   ,TM1.EFF_DT
   --PULLING IN THE DAILY HRS WORKED
   ,NVL(SUM(((to_number(SUBSTR(TM1.DAY_1, 1,INSTR(TM1.DAY_1, ':', 1, 1)-1),99))*60)+
             (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TM1.DAY_1,INSTR(TM1.DAY_1,':', -1, 1)+1),99))),0)
               "DAY1"
             ---AND THE REST OF THE DAYS FOR THE WORK PERIOD
FROM    PPRD_LINE TM1
JOIN    EMPL J ON TM1.EMPL_ID=J.EMPL_ID
WHERE
  J.EMPL_ID='some id number' --for test purposes, will need to break down to depts-

  AND J.EFF_DT >=TO_DATE('1/1/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')  
  AND(J.EXP_DT<=TO_DATE('12/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY') OR J.EXP_DT=TO_DATE('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY'))
GROUP BY
    J.EMPL_ID
   ,J.DEPT
   ,J.UNIT
   ,J.LAST_NM
   ,J.FIRST_NM
   ,J.TITLE 
   ,TM1.PPRD_ID
   ,TM1.EMPL_ID
   ,TM1.DOC_ID
ORDER BY
    MIN(J.EFF_DT)
   ,MAX(TM1.EFF_DT)
   ,MAX(TM1.EXP_DT)
```